# "Package dependencies cannot be resolved" when installing OpenJDK Runtime

Tags: software-center, java

When I try to install "OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime" from the Software Centre, this happens:

> Package dependencies cannot be resolved
>
> This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

To be on the safe side go back into USC and remove OpenJDK Java 7.  or Clean up open JDK:

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk*
```

To install OpenJDK Java 7

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consult the post below from the folks at Web UPD8 for install Oracle Java:

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html